# Flutter: SizedBox around button corrupts text alignment

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

I am building a keypad, however, fighting 2 strange behaviors since yesterday:

(1) my construction of the button with a SizedBox to create a square button causes a text alignment to the right. Actually it appears more like an offset, because if add a button with a longer text than 1, 2, 3 ("some text" in the snippet below), the text is not displayed. If I cut the text to the 1st character, this character will be shown.

(2) the keypad is hosted within a column. The column's crossAxisAlignment is center. While all column items I put above or below the keypad are centered, the keypad remains left. Also wrapping the CreateKeyPad in a Align or (as now in the snippet) Center the Row within CreateKeyPad does not help.

I have shrunk the code a bit to make it easier to understand, hope this still works.

In the screenshot below, the 0 on top is centered horizontally.
[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Tackle1x1Page extends StatefulWidget {
  Tackle1x1Page({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _Tackle1x1PageState createState() => _Tackle1x1PageState();
}

class _Tackle1x1PageState extends State<Tackle1x1Page> {
  int value = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                Text((value != null ? value : "0")),
                CreateKeypad(
                  prevInput: (value != null ? value : 0),
                  updtedInput: (int val) {
                    setState(() => value = val);
                  },
                ),
            ],
        ),),
    );
  }
}

// CREATE KEYPAD
class CreateKeypad extends StatelessWidget {
  final int prevInput;
  final Function(int) updtedInput;

  CreateKeypad({
    @required this.prevInput,
    @required this.updtedInput,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget> [
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CreateKey(
                keyValue: 1,
                keyReturnValue: (int val) {
                  updtedInput(prevInput != null? 10 * prevInput + val : val);
                },
              ),
              CreateKey(
                keyValue: 4,
                keyReturnValue: (int val) {
                  updtedInput(prevInput != null? 10 * prevInput + val : val);
                },
              ),
              CreateKey(
                keyValue: 7,
                keyReturnValue: (int val) {
                  updtedInput(prevInput != null? 10 * prevInput + val : val);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                CreateKey(
                  keyValue: 2,
                  keyReturnValue: (int val) {
                    updtedInput(prevInput != null? 10 * prevInput + val : val);
                  },
                ),
                CreateKey(
                  keyValue: 5,
                  keyReturnValue: (int val) {
                    updtedInput(prevInput != null? 10 * prevInput + val : val);
                  },
                ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 80.0,
                  height: 80.0,
                  child: Text("some text", style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black)),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ]
    ),);
  }
}

// CREATE SINGLE KEY
class CreateKey extends StatelessWidget {
  final int keyValue;
  final VoidCallback keyTabbed;
  final Function(int) keyReturnValue;

  CreateKey({
    @required this.keyValue,
    @required this.keyReturnValue,
    this.keyTabbed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 80.0,
          height: 80.0,
          child: CupertinoButton(
            child: Text(keyValue.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black)),

            onPressed: () {
              keyReturnValue(keyValue);
            },
            color: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CupertinoButton` has a default `padding` of `EdgeInsets.all(16.0)` if it isn't given a `color` and it has a default `padding` of `EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:14.0, horizontal: 64.0)` if it is given a `color`. To be able to center the `Text`, you can give it a padding of `zero`.

I provided an example using your code:

```
class CreateKey extends StatelessWidget {
  final int keyValue;
  final VoidCallback keyTabbed;
  final Function(int) keyReturnValue;

  CreateKey({
    @required this.keyValue,
    @required this.keyReturnValue,
    this.keyTabbed,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 80.0,
        height: 80.0,
        child: CupertinoButton(
          // remove the default padding 
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // new line
          child: Text(
            keyValue.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: CupertinoColors.black,
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            keyReturnValue(keyValue);
          },
          color: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

To center the keypad horizontally, set the `mainAxisAlignment` property of the `Row` to `MainAxisAlignment.center`.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
 return Center(
      child: Row(
        // set the mainaxisalignment property to center
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // new line
        children: <Widget>[
        ...... other widgets
```

Comment: Indeed, now I am able to use the CupertinoButton. Thanks! Why is this so? 2x16=32 should leave sufficient space in the middle for a 1 if the button is 80x80, or? And do you have any idea why the keypad is left aligned?

Comment: If you provide a `color` to the `CupertinoButton`, the default padding given is `EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 14.0, horizontal: 64.0`.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Especially with the padding, is there a way how you systematically found out, or did you know this from own experience and trial & error? I just started with flutter (and IntelliJ idea) and I am interested in chasing the issues myself instead of bothering you guys :-)

Comment: You can read the `docs` of each `widget` right within the IDE. Just hold `cmd + click` on the `Widget` and start reading about it!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try wrapping the `CupertinoButton` in a `Center` widget?

Comment: okay, try using InkWell
`child: InkWell(
onTap: () {
keyReturnValue(keyValue);
},
child: SizedBox(
width: 80,
height: 80,
child: Center(
child: Text(keyValue.toString(), style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.black)),
)
)
)
`

Comment: I guess this does not work with the CupertinoApp. I have material.dart included but I receive "No Material widget found."

Comment: make Inkwell the child of Material
`Material(child: Inkwell(...))`

Comment: I solved this part now with a RaisedButton from material. This works. So appears to be a problem with the CupertinoButton. However, the issue with the left align keypad remains. Any idea on that?

Comment: There is no issue with the `CupertinoButton`, I solved your issue with the `CupertinoButton`. Check my answer @w461